# Python. Instead of printing actual values from the Stack object it returns an address of that object

Tags: python-3.x, stack

Instead of printing actual values from the Stack object it returns an address of that object.

class Stack:
def **init**(self):
self._theItems = list()

```
def push(self, item):
    self._theItems.append(item)

def pop(self):
    assert not self.is_empty(), "Cannot pop from an empty stack"
    return self._theItems.pop()

def get_top(self):
    assert not self.is_empty(), "Cannot peek at an empty stack"
    return self._theItems[-1]

def is_empty(self):
    return len(self._theItems) == 0

def display(self):
    return self
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you have not defined any repr or str method. Please modify the program like shown below:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f'The customized stack has values: {self._theItems}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def display(self):
        return self.__repr__()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    customized_stack = Stack()
    customized_stack.init()
    customized_stack.push(10)
    customized_stack.push(20)
    customized_stack.push(30)
    customized_stack.push(40)
    print(customized_stack)
```

The when you run it, you get:

```
The customized stack has values: [10, 20, 30, 40]
```